# Sum values from child models using nested Subquery and annotaions in Django Viewset

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I'm trying to calculate the total price of a Recipe. To optimize DB queries I'm trying to use Django's ORM capabilities to perform the fewest requests.

My models.py is like this:

```py
class BaseRecipe(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(_('Base recipe title'), max_length=255, 
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_base_recipes')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['title']


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class IngredientBaseRecipe(models.Model):
    base_recipe = models.ForeignKey(BaseRecipe, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='ingredients')
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=255)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product)
    quantity = models.FloatField(_('Quantity'), default=0.0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-id']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=255, help_text=_('Product name'))
    price = models.FloatField(_('Sale price'), default=0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name', ]
        indexes = [models.Index(fields=['name',]), ]
```

Then in my Viewset I'm trying to get the BaseRecipes queryset with an annotated field that shows the sum of the ingredients prices. I get to the point to obtain the ingredients price, but I'm stucked trying to sum them in the BaseRecipe query set:

```py
min_price = (
    Product.objects.filter(name=OuterRef('name'))
        .annotate(min_price=Min('price'))
        .values('min_price')
)

ingredients_price = (
    IngredientBaseRecipe.objects
        .filter(base_recipe=OuterRef('id'))
        .annotate(price=Subquery(min_price))
        .order_by()
        .annotate(total=Sum(F('price') * F('quantity')))
        .values('total')
)

queryset = BaseRecipe.objects.filter(user=self.request.user) \
    .annotate(cost=Sum(ingredients_price))
return queryset
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got a solution by doing the Sum in the Subquery:

```py
min_price = (
    Product.objects.filter(name=OuterRef('name'))
        .annotate(min_price=Min('price'))
        .order_by()
        .values('min_price')
)
ingredients_price = (
    IngredientBaseRecipe.objects
        .filter(base_recipe__pk=OuterRef('id'))
        .prefetch_related('products')
        .select_related('base_recipe')
        .annotate(price=Subquery(min_unit_price))
        .values('base_recipe__pk')
        .order_by()
        .annotate(total=ExpressionWrapper(Sum(F('price') * F('quantity')), output_field=FloatField()))
        .values('total')
)
queryset = BaseRecipe.objects.filter(user=self.request.user) \
    .prefetch_related('ingredients', 'ingredients__products') \
    .annotate(cost=Subquery(ingredients_price))
return queryset
```